# ruby if hash keys include text, return hash key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash like so:

`hash = {2013 => 'one', 2014 => 'two'}`

and a variable `number`:

`number = 13`

I need to search through all of my hash keys and if `number` is included in a key, I need to return that key. Right now I have this:

```
if hash.keys.any? {|k| k.include? number}
  #do some work
end
```

That works, but I actually need to return `k` in the case that `k` does include `number`, not just check for it. How can I write that easily in a block "if" format like above.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the string representation of the key includes the string representation of the number?

Comment: your snippet throws an error (string vs fixnum) take a look at Array.find : ´hash.keys.find {|k| k.to_s.include? number.to_s}´

Comment: When you say "include", do you mean as a substring? Like `2013` "includes" `13`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
if result = hash.keys.find {|k| k.include? number}
  #do some work
end
```

Comment: In this case, how do I get the key? I need to be able to use the key that is found in my #do some work block

Comment: Ah, easy enough...thanks, and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if kv = hash.find { |k,v| k.to_s[number.to_s] }
  # do some work
end
```

For example, if `number = 13` then `kv == [ 2013, "one" ]` in the block. If not found, then `kv` is `nil` and the block is skipped.

Comment: +1 I'm a sucker for using `[...]` with strings to find sub-strings.

Comment: But I don't like seeing `if kv =...` at all so -1. Nah, I just find that a potential trouble-spot and maintenance issue and would flag it in a code review.

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert both values to strings and then just check if one string includes the other. Something like this:

```
hash.keys.select {|key| key.to_s.include? number.to_s }
```